# Importing Geometry from MSSQL to MySQL (Linestring)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, geometry, spatial

I've been given some data which I am trying to import into mysql, the data was provided in a text file format which is usually fine by me - i know mssql uses different data types so a SQL dump was a none starter...

For some reason mssql must store LINESTRINGS in reverse order, which seemed very odd to me. As a result of this, when i try to upload the file with navicat the import fails. Below is an example of the LINESTRING - as you can see the longitude is first, then the latitude - this is what i believe to be the issue?

LINESTRING (-1.61674 54.9828,-1.61625 54.9828)

Does anybody know how i can get this data into my database?

Im quite new to spatial/geometry extensions.

Thanks,

Paul

Answer (score 0):

must remember that the columns with spatial data have their own data type, navicat it does is call the "toString ()" or "AsText ()" event to display data, but in the background are blob, the advantage is that 2 are based on the standard WKT, I recommend that the db of origin to become space for text in the db destination takes that text and use it to "geometrifromtext" to convert the data (obviously you have to make a script with some programming language, with navicat can not do that)

[info wkt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text)

[info mysql spatial](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/creating-a-spatially-enabled-mysql-database.html)

[info sql server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895270.aspx#wkt)